# Which settings or configurations should I make to deploy the Hello World Play Framework application via boxfuse TO AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, playframework, cloudcaptain

I strictly follow the instruction on the Play framework and Boxfuse website when deploying the 2.8.x version of the the PLAY SCALA HELLO WORLD TUTORIAL application at https://developer.lightbend.com/start/?group=play&project=play-samples-play-scala-hello-world-tutorial.

When I deployed, I encountered the error "JVM exited with status 255".I was using Openjdk 1.8, Scala Sdk 2.3.14, and Play framework version 2.8.7.

```
WARNING: Run failed: Time out: Payload of Instance I-############# failed to come up within 300 seconds at http://:9000/
=> ensure your application responds with an HTTP 200 at / on port 9000
=> check the logs for I-############# in prod
=> ensure the healthcheck configuration (healthcheck.port, healthcheck.path, healthcheck.timeout) matches your application
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to go to your AWS account and check security and open up your IP ranges

Comment: Do you know how to set the IP ranges?